# mysql order by two unixtime columns combine

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Table `user` structure:

```
id(PK)(int)
name(varchar)
time1(int10) unixtime
time2(int10) unixtime

SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY `time1` DESC,`time2` DESC


 +------------------------------------------------------+
 | id        | name   |     time1     |     time2       |
 +------------------------------------------------------+
 | 12345     | Joe    |  1405605785   |   1406733506    |
 | 12346     | John   |  1406733506   |                 |
 | 12347     | David  |               |   1405684190    |
 +------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am using this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY `time1` DESC,`time2` DESC
```

How to combine two columns time to sort desc?

============

more example  reply for sagi

```
 +------------------------------------------------------+
 | id        | name   |     time1     |     time2       |
 +------------------------------------------------------+
 | 12345     | Joe    |  1            |   2             |
 | 12346     | John   |  5            |                 |
 | 12347     | David  |               |   4             |
 +------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to sort like that (DESC)

```
John (time = 5)
David (time = 4)
Joe (time  max value = 2)
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY coalesce(time1,time2) DESC`

Comment: Thanks juergen , but the result still like ORDER BY time1 DESC,time2 DESC

Comment: result is just can sort 1 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called conditional ordering using `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT * FROM `user` t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.time1 is null THEN t.time2 ELSE t.time1 END DESC
```

Could also be written as:

```
ORDER BY coalesce(t.time1,t.time2)
```

You didn't provide any expected results, and you didn't say by which column the result should be ordered in case both `time1,time2` are not `NULL` , so I assumed you want it to be ordered by the first column. If that's not the case, replace `time1` with `time2` .

Try this:

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(t.time1,t.time2) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result still like ORDER BY `time1` DESC,`time2` DESC

Comment: thanks sagi, But this sql just can sort time1, and time2 = value 0

Comment: Thanks sagi , Thank you let me know greatest function,`ORDER BY GREATEST(t.time1,t.time2) DESC` I using it fixed my problem

Comment: No problem mate, fixed the answer . @Sky